# Running a Compiled Lisp Program

Tags: emacs, lisp, common-lisp, slime

I'm guessing this is not rocket science, but how can I run a compiled lisp file?  I am using emacs and SLIME under Windows.  From the SLIME menu it is straightforward to compile the file and, once it does, it spits out a wx64fsl in the same directory as my lisp source.  How do I load/run this file?  I've been running files by eval-ing whole blocks of code and I've been told that running the compiled version performs far better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the SLIME REPL:

1. `,cd` to change directories into the one with your lisp file
2. `(load (compile "filename.lisp"))`

OR from the SLIME Menu:

SLIME > Compilation > Compile \ Load

So basically it was embarrassingly easy and there was even a menu option for it, I was just initially confused by the nomenclature.  Hopefully this will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 4):

`(LOAD "whatever")` will usually load and compile *whatever.lisp* unless a compiled file is already present with the same name and an implementation specific extension. Those files are generated with `(COMPILE-FILE "whatever.lisp")` or in emacs with SLIME using the keys `C-c C-k`.

As Rainer recommends, you probably should be using [ASDF](http://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/) to define your system, and most certainly [quicklisp](http://www.quicklisp.org/) for managing dependencies and installing packages. There is also **quickproject** which I recommend for creating a project template. You can install it with quicklisp easily.

Answer (score 3):

Is your lisp implementation automatically compiling functions? SBCL on OS X does for me. If that's the case, I don't think you'll see any benefit from using the compiled files, other than saving compile time when loading the file.

Example taken from [CLHS](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_cmpd_f.htm) and tested on my setup at the REPL:

```
(defun f (x) x)
F
> 
(compiled-function-p #'f)
T
>
```

In practice, I've always just used .lisp files. Never invested the time in using Make as a build tool to automatically compile lisp source code as it changes. I haven't seen any real-world benefits from using compiled fasls, at least on my setup, other than saving compile time (not speeding up run time).

And to save compile time, I use a technique where the majority of the packages/stable code are loaded up (automatically compiled) into the core file, so that compile time is minimal when I start with that core file and test some new code in a .lisp file.

Comment: The compilation model of the file compilation is slightly different. A file compiler can do more optimizations, may generate better messages in some cases and some errors can be detected early - during compilation. Often loading a source file is easy enough. I would recommend for larger pieces of code to use a system tool and load compiled code.